# Simplest way to draw filled triangles in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, fill

I have a set of triangles in the standard format used in matlab, i.e a `3XN` list of indinces, and two vectors of length `N`, called `X` and `Y` for the x and y coordinates.
I have a scalar value associated with each triangle, in a vector `C`. I want to draw filled triangles where the color of each tri is determined by the vector `C`. I know I can use `patch`, but that would mean I need to iterate over all tris and call `patch` for each one, right?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually if you check the [documentation for patch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) you'll notice it says

> Create one **or more** filled polygons.

It also says

> If X and Y are m-by-n matrices, MATLAB draws n polygons with m vertices.
>   C determines the color of the patch.

`patch` may actually be *exactly* what you want. You just need to put the `x` and `y` coordinates into `3xN` matrices.